# can i installl xerces 2.8 and 3.1 lib and dev, and easilly switch between them - maybe using update-alternatives?

Tags: package-management

I work on two different projects that use the two different versions, and I'd like to switch at will between them.

When I try to install package 'libxerces-c-dev' it wants to uninstall 'libxerces-c2-dev'.

How would I set up the two side-by-side using update-alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did;

- used synaptic to install `xerces-2` packages
- `cd /usr/include`
- `sudo cp -rp xercesc xercesc-28`
- used synaptic to install `xerces-3` packages
- `cd /usr/include`
- `sudo mv xercesc xercesc-31`
- `sudo ln -s xercesc-31 xercesc`

The above creates two key sym links; `/usr/lib/libxerces-c.so`, and `/usr/include/xercesc`. Now to configure `update-alternatives` to manage those two links for me;

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/libxerces-c.so libxerces /usr/lib/libxerces-c.so.28 1 --slave /usr/include/xercesc xerces-dev /usr/include/xercesc-28`

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/libxerces-c.so libxerces /usr/lib/libxercesc-3.1.so 2 --slave /usr/include/xercesc xerces-dev /usr/include/xercesc-31`

This allows me to select between the two libxerces alternatives, and slaves the xerces-dev selection to that choice, as well.  So, now I can switch between the two using;

- `sudo update-alternatives --config libxerces`

update-alternatives presents a text menu, which I don't really need because I know the option numbers from the '--install' commands.  To quickly bypass that, I added these to my ~/.bashrc

- `alias x28='echo "1" | sudo update-alternatives --config libxerces > /dev/null'`
- `alias x31='echo "2" | sudo update-alternatives --config libxerces > /dev/null'`